# How to handle merging of branches that are not in a sequence in combination with Flyway

Tags: flyway, git-flow

I just encountered the following situtation:

The test-server is currently running Flyway, with version 1 (`V1`). The test-server is automatically updated (including Flyway scripts) whenever anything is pushed on the `develop` branch.

A developer decides to start working on a new feature on branch `feature/123`. This developer creates a database script (Flyway compatible) called `V2__cool_feature.sql`. In the meantime, another developer also starts working on a feature branch called `feature/456`. This developer is also in need of an update script, and names it `V3__another_cool_feature.sql`, because the developer knows that `V2` is already used on another branch. This `feature/456` branch is finished and is merged, and so the current scripts on the develop branch are `V1` & `V3`. This works well and the V3 script is executed, leaving Flyway its `schema_version` on version 3.

The other feature branch `feature/123` is also merged, which means that the develop branch contains the scripts `V1`, `V2` & `V3`.

*Now this is were I'm having trouble with Flyway:*

The build, including Flyway, is executed and it leaves the following message:

```
[INFO] Database: jdbc:mysql://example.com:3306/my_schema (MySQL 5.5)
[INFO] Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.019s)
[INFO] Current version of schema `my_schema`: 3
[INFO] Schema `my_schema` is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

**What I want to happen is that the V2 script is executed, and I'm not sure how to do so.**

I hope I explained my problem well, if not, please leave a comment.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60206982/flyway-out-of-order-migration

Answer (score 3):

Ugh, I'm not a smart guy. Putting a bit more effort into my Googling skills lands me upon the Flyway documentation, describing **exactly** my problem:

Option:
outOfOrder

Required:
NO

Default:
false

Description:
Allows migrations to be run "out of order".
If you already have versions 1 and 3 applied, and now a version 2 is found, it will be applied too instead of being ignored. (Even the same versioning as in my question is used >.< )

Comment: can you put the link in Flyway documentation?

Comment: Sorry this is very old, I would have no idea where it is.

Comment: so with the practice that you mentioned your problem had been solved and already you ise it in your team ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `flyway.outOfOrder` configuration parameter to tell Flyway to run missing migration scripts instead of skipping them.

This property is set to `false` by default. You would have to set it to `true`.

In a Spring Boot application, you can set

> spring.flyway.out-of-order=true

In the command line, you can pass a JVM parameter

> -Dflyway.outOfOrder=true

For more details refer: [https://www.baeldung.com/flyway-migrations](https://www.baeldung.com/flyway-migrations.)