# Flyway out of order migration

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

Imagine I have the following flyway migrations:

- V1__create_table.sql
- V2__create_table.sql
- V4__create_table.sql

And these migrations have been applied to my database. Is there a possibility to add the following script:

- V3__create_table.sql

And let flyway run this migration out of order without complaining?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257976/how-to-handle-merging-of-branches-that-are-not-in-a-sequence-in-combination-with

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Flyway 2 has `flyway.outOfOrder` property which is by default `false`
You would have to set it to `true` to run your missing migration, as per [`migrate` docs](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate):

> Allows migrations to be run "out of order".
>
> If you already have versions 1 and 3 applied, and now a version 2 is found, it will be applied too instead of being ignored.

Comment: `spring.flyway.out-of-order` as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html